# counting the number of articles that do not possess specific words using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find which rows of my JSON file contain texts that do not possess certain words. The way I am trying to do it is though pandas and regular expressions in the following way:

```
# import json module for parsing
import json
import re
import pandas

keywords1 = ('economic', 'economy', 'economies', 'Economic', 'Economy', 'Economies')
keywords2 = ('uncertain', 'uncertainty', 'uncertanties', 'Uncertain', 'Uncertainty', 'Uncertanties')

for i in range(2005,2016):
    df = pandas.DataFrame([json.loads(l) for l in open('TH500_%d.json' % i)])

# match keywords
    matchingbodies = df[~df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords1))&~df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords2))].body
# Count by row

    counts = matchingbodies.groupby(lambda x: x.axes).agg(len)

    print(counts)
```

The idea is to group it by rows, axes, but I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'df'`. I know I am probably doing a stupid mistake... Cheers

Comment: IIUC you need `counts = matchingbodies.groupby(df.index).agg(len)` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jezrael, when I try that I get the following error:  'Grouper and axis must be same length'

Comment: Can you explain how you need groupby?  `matchingbodies.groupby(lambda x: x.axes).agg(len)` ? By column names, by some column, or by index?

Comment: Hi, I think I have framed the problem wrongly. What I would like to do is to retrieve first the count of how many articles do not contain the keywords stated and then to find a way to spot these articles (order in data.frame, for example number 13 and 46)

Comment: Ok, can you add sample of dataframe `df` (4,5 rows) and desired output?

Comment: I add some solution,  but I cannot test it because I have no `json` files. But I think you can check edit solution and if doesnt work, you can add sample of one `DataFrame` (or `json`) and add desired output, because it help me better understand what do you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need if need groupby by `index`:

```
counts = matchingbodies.groupby(df.index).size()
```

Or:

```
counts = matchingbodies.groupby(level=0).size()
```

EDIT:

It seems you need:

```
matchingbodies = df.loc[(~df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords1)) &
                        (~df.body.str.contains("|".join(keywords2))), 'body']
```

Comment: Hey, grouping by index sounds definitely convincing yes. When I try the first code I get that "AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length".

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: The matchingbodies is not the problem since I have used before and it was working. What does the loc do?

Comment: I use `loc` for selecting column `body` by condition - better explain with `ix` is in [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#if-then).

Comment: Hey! The midle code from your answer is giving me some results, which I think it might be what I am looking for. The only thing is that also retrieves, a minor error "minilenght must be positive" but it does not seem to be problematic. Thanks a lot!